# How to calculate deviations from the mean in R?

Tags: r

I am not talking about standard deviation.

For example, if I have a column of data:

```
3.600
1.800
3.333
2.283
4.533
```

and I want to calculate deviation from the mean for every row and save those deviations in a variable. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your data and `V1` is the column, you can do

```
new_var <- df$V1 - mean(df$V1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

To get an absolute difference in mean

```
new_var <- abs(df$V1 - mean(df$V1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!